# Hibernate not creating tables with HSQL and Spring

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, jetty

anybody has idea why hibernate is not creating tables in my example ?

Here's my web.xml - http://pastebin.com/ZaseSaBS

mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml - http://pastebin.com/LbdxMSAb

applicationContext.xml - http://pastebin.com/bAHMaVNX

console logs - http://pastebin.com/tTZZbxkX

I have similiar project with almost the same configuration and everything seems to run just fine on the other project. Any ideas why it's not creating tables here?
    I've one test enity in com.calculator.enity with @Entity @GeneratedValue annotations, i have it listed in persistence.xml file. There's also JpaRepository for this entity in com.calculator.repository

Comment: Can you try moving the hibernate properties to the "persistenceProvider" property in applicationContext.xml?  The other option is to put them in persistence.xml just to see if it works.  Spring can inject the properties for you if you define it as "persistenceUnit.hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"

Comment: This example does not show a persistence provider bean property in the factory bean so maybe that needs to be removed http://www.baeldung.com/2011/12/13/the-persistence-layer-with-spring-3-1-and-jpa/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your persistence configuration is not properly done. Use this sample persistence configuration as per your requirement. This is working fine for me.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd">



    <context:component-scan base-package="com.xxx.xxx"/>
    <tx:annotation-driven />
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactoryBean" />
    </bean>



    <bean id="entityManagerFactoryBean"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.xxx.xxx" />
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
        </property>

        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>


    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/test" />
        <property name="username" value="postgres" />
        <property name="password" value="prateek" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Comment: This is not working for me at all, console logs are the same...I changed the packages obviously. It's like it is just ignoring this configuration, zero logs from hibernate

Comment: I don't know what was the issue there but  I merged mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml  and applicationContext.xml and  it's working just fine now. Apparently it wasn't reading application-context.